# RewriteRules not stopping with LAST flag?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-2.2, rewrite

I seem to be having trouble with Apache 2.2's Rewrite module (running on FreeBSD 8).  My `.htaccess` file is as follows:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^xpaste$ cross.php [L]
RewriteRule ^x([a-f0-9]*)$ cross.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(gen|[a-f0-9]+)$ index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Yet somehow, the last rule overrides the other three.  As soon as I comment it out, the other rules work as expected:

- `www.example.com/xpaste` opens `cross.php`
- `www.example.com/x132633` opens `cross.php?id=132633`
- `www.example.com/gen` opens `index.php?gen`

I've tried various combinations of `L`, `NS`, and `S=n` flags on each `RewriteRule`, but unless I comment out the last rule, everything gets directed to `index.php`. How do I make Apache stop processing the `RewriteRule`s once it finds a match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RewriteRule generates an INTERNAL REDIRECT, then processing to be repeated starting from the first RewriteRule(RewriteRule ^xpaste$ cross.php [L]). You need add RewriteCond before last RewriteRule:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^xpaste$ cross.php [L]
 RewriteRule ^x([a-f0-9]*)$ cross.php?id=$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^(gen|[a-f0-9]+)$ index.php?$1 [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(cross|index)\.php$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html "[...] that if the RewriteRule generates an internal redirect[...], this will reinject the request and will cause processing to be repeated..."

Comment: Is there any more generic solution, something to tell Apache "don't process this rule if you're already handling a redirect"?

Comment: @DoktorJ You can use a condition to check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable. This is empty on the initial request and set to a non-empty string after the first rewrite (specifically, it's set to the HTTP status code).

Answer (score 0):

NS on the last rule should have worked. Could also do it on the other rules, with no harm. I'm getting to where I'm doing '[L,NS]', adding an NS wherever there's an L.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^xpaste$ cross.php [L]
RewriteRule ^x([a-f0-9]*)$ cross.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(gen|[a-f0-9]+)$ index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,NS]
```

I haven't tested these yet, but there's also an interesting approach here, for your more generic solution, using an IS_SUBREQ variable. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555247/can-anyone-think-of-when-a-sub-request-rewrite-is-useful

This post mentions REDIRECT_STATUS variable also.
http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4299003.htm

Comment: "NS on the last rule should have worked." - No it shouldn't have (and nor would the `IS_SUBREQ` server variable help here). A _subrequest_ (which is what the `NS` flag blocks) is not the same as an _internal rewrite_ - which is what's happening here. A subrequest is different and can be triggered by other modules such as mod_dir, SSI and HTTP error states. However, the `REDIRECT_STATUS` _environment variable_ IS an option here.